# Multi-objective genetic algorithm in Mathematica?

Tags: programming, mathematical-optimization

Is there any implementation of a multi-objective genetic algorithm for Mathematica?

Comment: Did you have a look at [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalNonlinearGlobalOptimizationExamples.html) together with method `DifferentialEvolution`?

Comment: @YvesKlett close but no cigar. Differential evolution is neither a multi-objective optimizer nor a genetic algorithm (it's more of an [evolution strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_strategy)). To my knowledge the answer is no; there certainly isn't anything in *Mathematica* itself for this. Anyway, this question by itself is not very informative; it would be useful to know what problem is being attacked here...

Comment: you may check http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EvolutionaryMultiobjectiveOptimization/

Answer (score 9):

I am currently developing an open source Genetic Algorithms library for *Mathematica*. It can be downloaded from [this source](https://github.com/Chipdelmal/Gattaca).
It is documented and, although I have not used it for multi-objective applications, it should provide some help with such applications.

---

*Edit by halirutan:* Unfortunately, the above link does not work anymore. If you search google for "Gattaca Hector Sanchez" you find traces of this repository but it seems it got deleted by the author.

Comment: Thanks for posting! It would be nice if you could provide a few usage examples in the answer

Comment: The documentation of the package has a few examples on how to use it. They are on the directory: /Genetic Algorithms/Documentation/English/Tutorials

Comment: I hope the examples and the package help. I am still working on it, specially in making it faster. I hope I can make some updates after I finish my exams. Have fun.

Comment: chipdelmal, I suppose you have been alerted by halirutan's edit to you post. However, I see that you have been active after this edit, so probably a reminder that the link no longer works is not too forward :). It sounds very interesting :)!

Comment: I'm sorry. I hadn't realised I deleted it from GitHub. The project can be found and downloaded from: 
https://bitbucket.org/chipdelmal/gattaca